# Blogger Search Label Conditional Statements

Tags: javascript, xml, blogger

I'm trying to add CSS in blogger based on URL. The URL is a search of multiple labels using: http://www.website.com/search/?q=label:Graphics|label:Identity|label:Brand . The search for multiple labels works, but I cannot figure out how to make a conditional statement for it.

I tried:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.canonicalUrl == &quot;http://www.website.com/search/?q=label:Graphics|label:Identity|label:Brand&quot;'>
    <style type="text/css">
        ...
    </style>
</b:if>
```

That won't work because of queries in the URL. So then I tried:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel == &quot;Graphics|Identity|Brand&quot;'>
    <style type="text/css">
        ...
    </style>
</b:if>
```

That doesn't work, nor does it seem proper. I'd rather have it done in XML, but if I cannot javascript will do. I even tried:

```
if(window.location('http://www.website.com/search/?q=label:Graphics|label:Identity|label:Brand') === 0)
    document.write("<style type='text/css'> ... </style>
);
```

BTW, the CSS must be in the doc, not an external source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can now use:

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel in ["Graphics", "Identity", "Brand"]'>
  <style type="text/css"> ... </style>
</b:if>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try do it separately for each tag:

`<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel == &quot;Graphics&quot;'>
    <style type="text/css">
        ...
    </style>
</b:if>`

then

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel == &quot;Identity&quot;'>
    <style type="text/css">
        ...
    </style>
</b:if>
```

and finally...

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel == &quot;Brand&quot;'>
    <style type="text/css">
        ...
    </style>
</b:if>
```

make sure you use the exact label with uppercase letters etc!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Blogger supports an OR operator in the XML template, so you should probably try to nest the conditions, something like:

```
if cond='data:blog.searchLabel == &quot;Graphics&quot;' [code]
else if cond='data:blog.searchLabel == &quot;Identity&quot;' [same code]
else if cond='data:blog.searchLabel == &quot;Brand&quot;' [same code again]
else [the other option]
```

Not very efficient, but unfortunately I don't see another solution...

Otherwise you could simply add the required style in the regular template, give it a class, and then use Java Script to dynamically add the class depending on the selected label.

Comment: Blogger OR operator works like this `<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel == &quot;Graphics+Identity+Brand&quot;'>`. I need AND/OR because I only want to filter posts that way using `display: none` and 'display:block' if statement is true. I just can't find any documentation on AND/OR search label conditions for Blogger. Here is the best information I can find on it thus far: http://exde601e.blogspot.com/2012/12/search-operators-for-Blogger-labels.html

Comment: I just now realized that was your Blog. :P